# Update increment_id from an existing invoice/creditmemo

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, creditmemo, database-update

I imported orders to Magento and during the import, invoices and creditmemo have been created.
But I want to change the increment_id of these invoices/creditmemo so that it'll be coherent for accounting.

I update the increment_id in the database in the bases **sales_flat_invoice** and **sales_flat_creditmemo**. And I purged the caches before reloaded the admin panel page. But in the admin panel, there are the old numbers.

What can I do to update these id and make them visible from the admin panel ?
Or is it possible to generate the invoice and creditmemo choosing the id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find a solution, I have to update the increment_id in **sales_flat_invoice_grid** too and put the same id as in **sale_flat_invoice** (for invoices, same for creditmemo).

Comment: That should be fine, increment_ids are not referenced (they use entity_ids). Although **make sure** that you also update the last increment id in `eav_entity_store`, or you could run into issues

Comment: If the last id I put for an invoice (for example) is 42, I should put the same in the last_increment_id or 43 ? (thx because I forgot to do that too)

Comment: Put the same value. Basically the last_increment_id should be the `MAX(increment_id)` of the relevant tables (...._order, _invoice,_creditmemo, _shipment)